# Autodownload apps that installed on another tablet?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

Is there a solution without any extra app or software for the following:

I have here an old Acer A510 Tablet with my account, also a new Xperia Z2 Tablet - I would like to force the play store on the Z2 Tablet to download every app that I already installed on the old tablet. Is there a way without a backup app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes, there is](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/113410?hl=en), both from the device, or using Google Play on a 'regular computer'.

#### Using your mobile device

> 1. Open the  Google Play Store app
> 2. Touch the  Play Store icon and select My Apps.
> 3. Visit the All category.
> 4. Select an app you’d like to install, then touch the Install button on the app’s detail page.

#### Using your computer

> 1. Visit your [My Apps page on Google Play](https://play.google.com/apps).
> 2. Select an app to view its detail page.
> 3. Click the button that says Install or Installed and select the device where you’d like to install the app.
>    Note: When an app shows an "Installed" button on its detail page, it means that the app is installed on one of the devices associated with your Google Account.
> 4. Click Install.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do one thing...rather then again installing the apps on the New tablet...install ES File Explorer on your old tablet...goto App Manager and tale backup of all apps..and then send that folder to new device..and without any internet connection..Install all the .apk (application) files your want..!!

Comment: Or titanium backup pro can do all apps and data in one click!